# WebSupergoo.ABCpdf Test application does not work

Tags: c#, .net, html, pdf, abcpdf

I recently cleaned up my Windows 7 64-bit PC, and after it ABCpdf8 started giving me an error, when I try to export HTML to PDF.
The error is "Failed to initiate IE compatibility mode: Failed to load all required assemblies."
at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Internal.IECompatibility.Activate()
at line

```
theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl(input.Text);
```

of the test application, and I have no idea why, because I did not remove any assemblies from my machine. 
If I run the compiled application on another workstation with the same config (Windows 7 64-bit), it works fine. Dependency Walker images showed no difference in DLLs sets from my machine and from another.
How else can I identify the source of the problem?
It is definitely neither a missing DLL, nor the user access to the system folders, because, I checked user rights as well, they're identical on both machines.
I assume that it might be a corrupted registry entry. Is there any way to quickly check the assumption?

It has to be said that, ABCpdf comes as third-party tool within another software, so I cannot contact support directly, but through the main vendor.

Answer (score 3):

I had a [similar problem](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/windows-update-killed-my-abcpdf/) with different behavior on w7 and ws2008, which was solved by using the Gecko engine

```
doc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
```

Note that [websupergoo recommends using Gecko](http://www.websupergoo.com/support.htm) rather than IE9 as parts of the IE API it uses have been deprecated. (item 6.29)

Comment: Well, even if in the project I can change Engine, ABCpdf is a third-party tool within another software, and I cannot change anything there. However, I tried to install the latest version of ABCpdf8, and it worked! Now, the question is when the main vendor will integrate the latest version in their product.

Comment: I'm so glad I found this answer. Our client upgraded IE on their server to a version not supported by ABCpdf8, changing the browsing engine fixed the PDF generation.

Answer (score 0):

When you 'cleaned' your system you may have erased the license key from the registry. Try re-installing your 'other software'.

Comment: i did it. I'm trying to monitor the test application with ProcessMonitor to see which registry entries it tries to refer to.

Comment: ok, I figured out that HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\Cache and HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\ have ACCESS DENIED result on my workstation and SUCCESS on another workstation. I checked permissions on both machines and they're the same! What is going on here? Why then test application does not have access to registry entries on my machine?

Comment: fixed access to those entries, but still no luck. the same error, and no ACCESS DENIED errors in ProcessMonitor

Comment: If you're using ABCpdf as I have, you have to allow read/write/delete access to the directory where your source HTML document reside.

Comment: Hmm, ProcessMonitor shows "ACCESS DENIED" events for process "C:\Temp\ABCpdf\MSHtml\4r4ctabh.3s1\mshtmlwp.exe" when it tries to reach "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\security.config.cch.new". But I cannot change security settings for that folder. How can I give the permissions?